# Quoting codes in a list leaves a </li>

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

- I found this by accident;
- If I am writing a list and start quoting

> ```
> \some \codes \then \there \is \an \unexpected </li>
> ```
>
> Is it a bug or I should not do so?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the escapes, just "  - " followed by ">    " on the next line produces a `</li>`.   This is close to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161275 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153326.  May be you should try posting there.

Comment: [I've started a discussion on Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2940125#2940125) in this regard... Things are brewing.

Comment: ...apparently [it's complicated](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2971280#2971280).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see [on the revision page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5942/revisions) which shows a live rendering of this question, this is fixed now. It's still visible in your question because the version displayed here is saved on submission; were you to edit the question now, the stray `</li>` would be gone from there as well.

If you're interested in some technical background on the problem, I gave a bit of explanation in [Blockquotes in a list break blockquotes after the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153326/blockquotes-in-a-list-break-blockquotes-after-the-list/259111#259111).